# Search function failing me asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a simple search box.  I don't receive any errors, my variable is populating correctly, but it's not updating the query.  Here is my controller.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
    {
        ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastname_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = sortOrder == "firstname" ? "firstname_desc" : "firstname";
        var users = from u in UserManager.Users
                       select u;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            users = UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.LastName.Contains(searchString));
                                   //|| u.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "lastname_desc":
                users = UserManager.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastName);
                break;
            case "firstname":
                users = UserManager.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
                break;
            case "firstname_desc":
                users = UserManager.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastName);
                break;
            default:
                users = UserManager.Users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
                break;
        }
        return View(users.ToList());

    }
```

And I have this within my view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

I have a LastName field within the applicationuser model, if I have a last name of Smith and I type in S, searchString populates with "S" while debugging, but the view is not updated.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last switch statement that is trying to handle sort order sets `user` to new values at each branch. All the upper assignments to the `user` are lost, including that assignment which filters your users:

```
users = UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.LastName.Contains(searchString));
```

You should use `UserManager.Users` only once. Since we don't see sort order stuff, or your object types completely I can not provide an exact solution but something like this might work:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lastname_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm = sortOrder == "firstname" ? "firstname_desc" : "firstname";

    var users = from u in UserManager.Users
                   select u;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(u => u.LastName.Contains(searchString));                                   
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "lastname_desc":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastName);
            break;
        case "firstname":
            users = users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
            break;
        case "firstname_desc":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastName);
            break;
        default:
            users = users.OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
            break;
    }
    return View(users.ToList());

}
```

There is a possibility that type mismatches might occur, then you can define separate `IEnumerable` or `List` type variables at each step instead of rewriting users each time.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think it was a combination of issues.  I took out the 2nd usermanager and also put the switch about the string check and now it all works.  It was your point about the switch clearing everything - thanks again.